How ignore foreign key migration in general?
I have a question about migrations in Laravel. Is it possible to handle foreign keys with a simple if statement? Specifically, I want to ensure that if a foreign key already exists, it should not be migrated again. Is there a straightforward way to do this?
This is my code for example.
        if (Schema::connection('orders_import')->hasTable('mymuesli_label')) {
            Schema::connection('orders_import')->table('mymuesli_label', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->foreign(['roll'], 'roll_id')->references(['id'])->on('mymuesli_roll');
            });
        }

        if (Schema::connection('orders_import')->hasTable('parameter_mapping')) {
            Schema::connection('orders_import')->table('parameter_mapping', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->foreign(['customer'], 'parameter_mapping_fk_customer')->references(['id_customer'])->on('customer');
            });
        }

        if (Schema::connection('orders_import')->hasTable('product_mapping')) {
            Schema::connection('orders_import')->table('product_mapping', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->foreign(['customer'], 'product_mapping_fk_customer')->references(['id_customer'])->on('customer');
            });
        }


I think this will be the straightforward method with an if statement.
Here is your updated migration code.
    if (Schema::connection('orders_import')->hasTable('parameter_mapping')) {
        Schema::connection('orders_import')->table('parameter_mapping', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if (!Schema::hasColumn('parameter_mapping','parameter_mapping_fk_customer')) {
                $table->foreign(['customer'], 'parameter_mapping_fk_customer')->references(['id_customer'])->on('customer');
            }
        });
    }

    if (Schema::connection('orders_import')->hasTable('product_mapping')) {
        Schema::connection('orders_import')->table('product_mapping', function (Blueprint $table) {
            if (!Schema::hasColumn('product_mapping','product_mapping_fk_customer')) {
                $table->foreign(['customer'], 'product_mapping_fk_customer')->references(['id_customer'])->on('customer');
            }
        });
    }

Just use If(!Schema->hasColumn('table_name', 'column_name'))
This method has two parameters, hasColumn('table_name', 'column_name')

I believe yes, but with laravel 11. With Schema::getForeignKeys('your_table'). I will do an example for your first code:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

$foreignKeys = Schema::connection('orders_import')->getForeignKeys('mymuesli_label');
$foreignKeyExists = false;

foreach ($foreignKeys as $foreignKey) {
    if ($foreignKey['name'] === 'roll_id') {
        $foreignKeyExists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$foreignKeyExists) {
    Schema::connection('orders_import')->table('mymuesli_label', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign(['roll'], 'roll_id')->references(['id'])->on('mymuesli_roll');
    });
}

// Then set the $foreignKeyExists to false and keep with the search on your tables.

ps: This method gives you an array of arrays with name (string) and columns (array of strings), and you need to get it right with the migration ->foreign($columns, $name).

Sorry, I might have missed mentioning that there could potentially be around 700 instances where this issue might occur. I generated new migrations using this package https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator for a very large project. On localhost, it can unfortunately happen that there are problems with foreign keys where a foreign key might already exist. I need a solution that can handle this entire block of code with an if statement without individually listing the foreign keys, but I'm not sure if that's possible. @francisco
